Jupyter Colab Not Updating UI with background task or thread
I'm running a small POC to see if the ipython display can be updated in the background with a task or thread using below sample code.
The UI is updating when the slider or the button was invoked but not without.
Please advise:
import nest_asyncio, asyncio
import threading

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

%gui asyncio

import ipywidgets, asyncio, time
from IPython import display
from tqdm.asyncio import tqdm as async_tqdm
output = ipywidgets.Textarea()
running = ipywidgets.ToggleButton(description="start", icon="play")
interval = ipywidgets.FloatSlider(description="loop interval", value=1, min=0.001, max=10) # zero can hang if you don't await
progress = ipywidgets.FloatProgress(value=0.0, min=0.0, max=10.0)
progress2 = display.ProgressBar(10)
ui = ipywidgets.VBox([ipywidgets.HBox([running, interval]), output, progress])
tasks = dict()

display.display(ui, progress2)

async def async_function():
    await asyncio.sleep(0.1)

async def tqdm_progress():
  for _ in async_tqdm(range(100), desc="Async Operation"):
    await async_function()

async def update_progress():
    t = 0
    while running.value or t < 10:
      progress.value = float(t/10)
      t += 1
      progress2.progress = t
      progress2.update()
      display.clear_output(wait=True)
      display.display(ui, progress2)
      await asyncio.sleep(1)

async def main():
  def do_work(t):
      global output
      global progress
      output.value = f"{t}: {time.time()}"
      progress.value = float(t/20)

  async def do_loop():
      t = 0

      while running.value:
          do_work(t)
          t += 1
          await asyncio.sleep(interval.value)

  def on_running_changed(*change):
      task = tasks.pop("do_loop", None)
      output.value = f"maybe stopping {task}..."
      if task:
          output.value = f"stopping {task}..."
          # task.cancel()
      if running.value:
          output.value = "starting..."
          # tasks["do_loop"] = loop.create_task(do_loop())
          tasks["do_loop"] = "Test"
          # threading.Thread(target=update_progress).start()
          # Process(target=update_progress).start()

  running.observe(on_running_changed, "value")

loop.create_task(update_progress())
loop.create_task(main())

I tried various UI components with asyncio and threading.
